# Android import exception

Tags: android

When importing an existing Android project through git I got this error :

> An internal error occurred during: "Re-indexing repository
>   [ProjectName]". java.lang.NullPointerException

Also it does not build now
Build Error:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try
>   building this project [Project Name] Unknown  Java Problem

Any idea ?

Comment: Add Android Sdk With Project